# How to add authentication for Swift in Xcode environment

Tags: swift, authentication, artifactory, swift-package-manager

The Swift package manager recently added support for registries for hosting binary packages. I have successfully created Swift packages and resolved them from a local Artifactory instance.

Setting up authentication directly for Swift can be done through the commandline:

`swift package-registry set --global "https://artifactory.com/api/swift/swift"`

`swift package-registry login "https://artifactory.com/api/swift/swift" --username=MyUser --password=MyPassword`

Now you can simply invoke: `swift package resolve` from the location of your `Package.swift` file.

However, Xcode seem incapable of reusing the stored credentials.

Is it possible to set up XCode such that the integrated Swift version has credentials for authentication? If it is possible, how is it done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug on Xcode side.

[Xcode 14.3 doesn't use credentials (from netrc or keychain) for auth to spm registry](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/issues/6395)

Seems the fix is included in the Xcode 15 Beta!

Comment: We tried Xcode 15 Beta, and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps one of the solutions in the relevant JFrog Knowledge Base will do the trick?
https://jfrog.com/help/r/artifactory-how-to-configure-a-swift-registry-and-resolve-related-errors/how-to-configure-a-swift-package-registry

Comment: That is unfortunately not applicable, as it only showcases how to add a registry with no authentication. Our Artifactory instance does not allow anonymous access, thus authentication is required.